# Ошибка в коде: "Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения"

Tags: c

Работал с указателями по заданию с университета, в котором требовалось исправить все ошибки. 

Исправил, запускаю - код работает, ввожу значение b, нажимаю Enter и код вылетает с сообщением ниже: "Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. m было nullptr."

Вот сам код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char* p, c;
    int* a;
    float* x, y = 3.5;
    double* m, n;

    int b;
    a = &b;
    printf("  Enter b = ");
    scanf_s("%d", &b);
    printf("a = %p\t*a = %d\tb = %d\n", a, *a, b);
    p = (char*)a;
    c = *p;
    *p = *(p + 3);
    *(p + 3) = c;
    printf("p = %p\tc = %d\ta = %p\tb = %d\n", p, c, a, b);
    x = &y;
    printf("x = %p\t*x = %f\ty = %f\n", x, *x, y);
    *a = *x;
    *a = *x;
    printf("a = %p\t*a = %d\tx = %p\t*x = %f\ty = %f\n", a, *a, x, *x, y);
    a = &b;
    y = 12345.6789;
    printf("x = %p\t*x = %f\ty = %f\n", x, *x, y);
    *p = *x;
    c = *p;
    *p = *(p + 3);
    *(p + 3) = c;
    printf("p = %p\tc = %d\tx = %p\ty = %f\n", p, c, x, y);
    m = &n;
    printf("m = %p\t*m = %lf\tn = %lf\n", m, *m, n);
    n = 5.5;
    printf("m = %p\t*m = %lf\tn = %lf\n", m, *m, n);
    b = n = y = 1.7;
    printf("b = %d\ty = %f\tn = %lf\n", b, y, n);
    printf("*a = %d\t*x = %f\t*m = %lf\n", *a, *x, *m);
    m += 2;
    printf("n = %lf\tn = %p\tm = %p\n", n, &n, m);
    *m = (float)* a - n + (int)* x;
    printf("  m = %p\t*m = %lf\n", m, *m);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибку выдает в последней строке кода, прямо перед командой system("pause"), как её исправить - понятия не имею, буду благодарен за любую помощь или хотя бы подсказку.
[image: Mistake]

Comment: Так а что вы ожидали? Кто вам разрешил делать `m += 2;`? Куда после этого будет указывать ваше `m`?

Comment: Мне это по условию задания необходимо прописать

Comment: Ну так тогда не удивляйтесь, что код падает. Через такое `m` вы записываете что-то "в никуда". Последствия такого шага непредсказуемы.

Comment: Такой важный комментарий мне конечно же поможет. Спасибо.

Comment: @Anatolb Не знаю, что подразумевал человек, который писал такое задание, т.к. полагаю, что многие строки можно исправить по-разному. Возможно, это Вам поможет:```*(m) += 2;```. Если, конечно, суть этой строки была такой)